# structured numpy ndarray, how to get values

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, key-value, numpy-ndarray

I have a structured numpy ndarray la = {'val1':0,'val2':1} and I would like to return the vals using the 0 and 1 as keys, so I wish to return val1 when I have 0 and val2 when I have 1 which should have been straightforward however my attempts have failed, as I am not familiar with this structure.

How do I return only the corresponding val, or an array of all  vals so that I can read in order?

Comment: This `{'val1':0,'val2':1}`, is a dictionary, not a structured array. If you do have one please share a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

When you save a Python object (non-array), `numpy` wraps it in an array.  The object is `pickled`:

```
In [112]: np.save('test.npy', {'foo':34})
```

In newer `numpy` versions, you have to explicitly allow it to load pickled items:

```
In [113]: data = np.load('test.npy')                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-c5835e6fb31e> in <module>
----> 1 data = np.load('test.npy')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
    451             else:
    452                 return format.read_array(fid, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
--> 453                                          pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
    454         else:
    455             # Try a pickle

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.py in read_array(fp, allow_pickle, pickle_kwargs)
    720         # The array contained Python objects. We need to unpickle the data.
    721         if not allow_pickle:
--> 722             raise ValueError("Object arrays cannot be loaded when "
    723                              "allow_pickle=False")
    724         if pickle_kwargs is None:

ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False


In [115]: data = np.load('test.npy',allow_pickle=True)                                 
In [116]: data
```

The result is an object dtype array with 1 element (0d)

```
Out[116]: array({'foo': 34}, dtype=object)
```

`tolist` can extract that object, as will `item()`.

```
In [117]: data.tolist()                                                                
Out[117]: {'foo': 34}
In [118]: data.tolist()['foo']                                                         
Out[118]: 34
In [119]: data.item()                                                                  
Out[119]: {'foo': 34}
In [120]: data[()]                                                                     
Out[120]: {'foo': 34}
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a dictionary, rather than an ndarray. Assuming you don't have multiple keys associated with the same value, you reverse the dictionary with

```
la_reversed = {v: k for k, v in la.items()}
```

so `la_reversed[0]` would be `'val1'` and `la_reversed[1]` would be `'val2'`.

You can get a list of values in the dictionary with `list(la.values())`.

Comment: In my debugger it says it is an ndarray and when I try to use items or values as I would with a dictionary I get:
labels = list(lb.values())
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an MCVE per yatu's comment or at least the declaration of this variable in your code?

Comment: It is a variable I saved as .npy and the variable is actually the class indices value that I get while creating training dataset generators in keras: train_generator.class_indices, here (https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) it says: The dictionary containing the mapping from class names to class indices can be obtained via the attribute class_indices.

Comment: and I save it as:
labels = (train_generator.class_indices)
np.save('/home/d/Desktop/s/classes', labels)

Comment: If the documentation states that class_indices should be a dictionary, I'm not sure why that wouldn't be the case in your code. Again, if you provide more code it will be easier to determine what the problem is.

Comment: I am not sure, could it be the way I save, although I don't do anything special. It really is all there is, I can't think of a minimal working code excluding the output of keras class_indices, Just found out that I can use la.tolist() and it returns a dictionary, somehow? when I wanted a list, alas from there on I was able to solve my problem. Sure would like to know why though.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your statement about saving. `numpy.save` saves ndarray data, and I'm assuming you're loading with a numpy function too, which likely loads it as an ndarray. Calling `tolist` would just return a standard Python list, but even in that case a list doesn't have `items` or `values` methods, so I'm assuming you indexed the list to retrieve the dictionary, which would be the first element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that I can use la.tolist() and it returns a dictionary, somehow? when I wanted a list, alas from there on I was able to solve my problem.